# Max number in array of strings that include numbers

Tags: ruby, string

I have a list of file names in an array `@filtered_reports`. The file names, for example, are `'settlement_report_1.csv'` and various other names reports all the way up to 200+. There are no leading zeroes. When using `array.max` I get `'settlement_report_99.csv'` as the max value when the largest sequential is `'settlement_report_236.csv'`.

Before I hit triple digits, it worked fine like this:

```
@filtered_reports.max
```

which returns `99` instead of `236` or any other 3+ digit number that's higher than `99`.

How can I grab the largest numbered report out of the array regardless of the length of the number instead of the highest first digit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `#max` on an array of strings.  Ruby doesn't inherently know that you're trying to sort by a given number in that string, and so it sorts it alphanumerically instead.

Ruby will need to know to compare these values as integers.  Here is one such solution that should work:

`@filtered_reports.max { |a, b| a.slice(/\d+/).to_i <=> b.slice(/\d+/).to_i }`

Comment: `max_by` rather than `max` is faster (and more readable, too): `.max_by { |x| x[/\d+/].to_i }`